# How to expand a canvas frame to the root mainwindow using grid tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, grid, scrollbar

I just created a canvas and a frame with vertical & horizontal scrollbars where I placed some objects. Now what I want to do is to let the size of the frame containing the scrollbars to be the same as my mainwindow, in other words, when I make the root bigger, then the frame should get bigger and have exactly the size of the root. In my code, I have to set the width and height of my canvas otherwise I get a window with size "0x0".
This is my code:

```
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("400x400")
        self.canvas = Frame(self.root)
        #self.canvas.config(width=700, height=900)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
        self.canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas.grid_propagate(True)
        self.new_canvas = Canvas(self.canvas)
        self.new_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news")
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.new_canvas.yview)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.vsbb = Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="horizontal", command=self.new_canvas.xview)
        self.vsbb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')

        self.new_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.new_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.vsbb.set)
        self.out_frame = Frame(self.new_canvas)
        self.new_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.out_frame, anchor="nw")

        self.root.title("TIxS3 Master Control v3.1")
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)

# Here come my Objects to insert in the frame "out_frame"

        self.out_frame.update_idletasks()
        self.new_canvas.config(scrollregion=self.new_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

How can I solve that using grid? I am not sure about the solution in pack but I think I should do the same thing as pack(fill= BOTH) does right?

Comment: Take a look into `column_configure()` and so on

Comment: Why did you name your frame `self.canvas`?